# How to pass data between objects

Tags: java

I am trying to pass some information between the classes like success or failure, reason of failure, missing data etc.
But I am not sure which is the right way to do this. Also I can not pass information as parameter as I need to retrieve it back. Can not return any value as there are return values already.
For example : suppose I have classes like this(its just dummy code actual code is very long)

```
class A {
   B b = new B();
   C c = new C();
   b.putData();
   c.putData();

   //Want to print all the inforamtion of what happend 
   //in methods of putData and getData. How to do that?
}   

class B {

   boolean putData() {
      D d = new D();
      Data data =d.getData();
      //some code goes here
   }
}
Class C{
   boolean putData() {
      //some code here
   } 
}
```

Comment: pass an object as parameter?

Comment: `Want to print all the inforamtion of what happend in methods of putData and getData.` in the simplest way `add System.out.println(...)` statements for the values you are interested in. The better way: rephrase your question to be clear what you want ot achieve.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I cannot pass as parameter as I have to retrieve it back, which I can’t do as all the methods arealready  returning some objects.

Comment: I can do System.out.println(...), only when I have that inforamtion. But my real problem is how to retrive it. It doesnt matter it come as a list or map or String

Comment: What's wrong with creating getter methods?

Comment: "the methods are already returning some objects" then change the return value to do what you want, no?

Comment: Can you please provide some small example of how to do it using getter methods @E_net4

Answer (score 0):

See if below code can help you.

```
class A {
  B b = new B();
  C c = new C();
  String resultClassB = b.putData();
  String resultClassC = c.putData();

  System.out.println(resultClassB);
  System.out.println(resultClassC)

  //Want to print all the inforamtion of what happend 
 //in methods of putData and getData. How to do that?
}   

class B {

  String putData() {
   D d = new D();
   String data =d.getData();
  //some code goes here

  return data'

 }

}
Class C {
     String putData() {
     //some code here
     String result = "reason for failure and success";
     return result'
   } 
}

class Data (){
    String getData(){
        String data = "get all data to print using some logic";
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help E_net4. I can use getter methods. But Still I will appreciate if you can help with some small sample code.

Comment: Just a heads up: that's not my answer. I would rather split putting the data and getting the outcome in separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with try{}catch(Exception){}  to get information when things go wrong.

Succes would be a valid return Object.

```
 class A {
           B b = new B();
           C c = new C();
           b.putData();
           try
           {
                c.putData();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               //do error handling, or print stacktrace
           }

          //Want to print all the inforamtion of what happend 
         //in methods of putData and getData. How to do that?
        }   

    class B {

        boolean putData() {
           D d = new D();
           Data data =d.getData();
          //some code goes here
        }
     }
        Class C{
        boolean putData() throws Exception{
            if(<data_missing>) throw new Exception("Data missing");
        } 
 }
```

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of printing al the information is? Do you actually need it in the code, or are you trying to create a logger?